# Unable to upload leads There are no leads in list_id

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I have installed VICIDIAL VERSION: 2.14-679a BUILD: 180618-2300 on Ubuntu 16.04

When I am uploading leads on vicidial campaign, it shows :
Done GOOD: 10000 BAD: 1 TOTAL: 10001

But when I go to that list, it shows 0 leads, when I try to download lead list, it shows this error: There are no leads in list_id: 1111

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Likly you uploaded to other list. Check in mysql in table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During upload of leads in Vicidial, you have the option to "override the list_id" by selecting a list from the dropdown menu. Of course, this requires that you first Create the list so it appears in the dropdown. If you do not avail yourself of this override option, then the list id must be the 3rd field in the CSV or Tabbed data file unless you choose "Custom layout" in the "File Layout to use:" section.

Look here for the field order:

http://SERVER_IP/vicidial/help.php?ADD=99999#list_loader

If you have random values in the 3rd field, then your leads may have landed in random lists. If you have NOTHING in the 3rd field, they may all have landed in the "list zero" which is awkward because you can not create a list with less than 100 as the ID. Delete them from mysql directly and try again. Perhaps with The Vicidial Manager's Manual as your guide this time (free version on the EFLO.net site, the owners of the software).